# Create type keys dynamically in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to generate the type keys from a combination of other type's key, like create dynamically object's keys.

```js
type Swatch = {
  dark: string;
  light: string;
};

type ColorTheme = {
  primary: Swatch;
  secondary: Swatch;
};

// The result should be
type CombineType: {
  // This keys are dinamically created as a combinatino of Swatch and ColorTheme keys

  // primaryDark: string
  // secondaryDark: string
}
```

Comment: Oh this is a nice little template literal type question but I’m on mobile so someone else will almost certainly get here first!  If not I’ll answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating some kind of "generator" generic type that will give you the expected output.

```
type First = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

type Second = {
  first: string;
  second: string;
}

type JoinKeys<FK, SK> = 
  FK extends string ?
    SK extends string ?
      `${FK}${Capitalize<SK>}`
    : never
  : never;

type CombineTypes<F,S> = {
  [key in JoinKeys<keyof F,keyof S>]: string;
};

type Test = CombineTypes<First, Second>;
```

Type `JoinKeys` simply combines passed in key values.
Type `CombineTypes` is a simple generic type that takes two params and outputs a type, where key is joined by `keyof` both passed params

You should extend these a bit to make sure only objects can be passed in and to have proper type coverage :)

Here is working example in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7CgXigbwLACgpQBmA9sQFxQoJwB2A5gNx4EBGAhghVbY3gL5NceUJCgBlCAGNiNACboszIohRdg1eoIJIpM2Wo29cfPMPDQAUsVoBpCCCQAeGDYA04mwD4FSl1AgAHsAQckiU6jxQAPxKBGI2-kEhsmHc9NGxBFAABgAkmC58+QDCbGBwwGwANnAAXhCO8Z582ZkUNBAAbhAISu1dPYJmosXEALYstBAAKuZOMK5i3hg4+FAA2gDW9lC0UFa29k7bIMSEsK4nZ+KeALoGPIICprgi0NMQKAqjE1OzkPMVMB3BJpHJPAwgA)

Comment: Don't forget about [the `Capitalize` type](https://tsplay.dev/NDP36N) :)

Comment: Oh just saw he is expecting camel case, good point :)